# Race conditions in AWS Lambda- file lock and async-await?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, async-await, race-condition

I have an S3 bucket, which periodically receives uploads. Upon a csv upload, a lambda function is triggered to read the file, perform some processing steps, read a json file, and update the json file to include data from csv.

This supports an internal tool; so I don't expect dozens, let alone thousands of concurrent requests. However, <= 5 concurrent requests is a possible occurrence.

If two colleagues upload a csv file at the same time, the lambda will retrieve the same json file and update it. The first Lambda invocation will effectively be erased by the second.

I see that [S3 object lock](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lock.html) allows me to prevent read/write operations while the object is locked. To complicate matters, a production application will read this JSON file several times an hour. So globally locking the file is not an option.

Questions

1. Can I lock files to *specific applications*, not globally? (ex: just to my lambda function)
2. Can AWS Lambda support asynchronous functions (ex: asyncio in Python)?
3. If async is supported and I can lock the JSON file, specific to the Lambda function, could the Lambda function await file unlock?
4. Am I greatly overcomplicating this? Perhaps I can turn concurrency down to 1 invocation and use SQS to queue requests.

Answer (score 0):

Question #1, no.

some background knowledge

1. object lock includes legal hold and retention lock (and two retention modes:compliance and governance), legal hold has on/off state, retention has lock util-date (if the date is before lock util-date, object can not be deleted). and governance mode can disable lock before lock util-date if you have the permission.
2. when a json file was object locked, write a same location file again, it will not be overwrite, it will generate with a new version. so if avoid this case, different json file name is required.

Comment: A production application retrieves values from the JSON file so I am inherently constrained to using the same JSON file.